# Error while trying to execute cron script with space in path

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a script with several rsync commands in it. The script file is placed in an NTFS partition with owner and group permissions set to root.

I have no problems running the file manually from the terminal using the command:

```
"/mnt/Files/Software/Software Customizations/Linux/Scripts/rsync_backup.sh"
```

The crontab entry is (my crontab, not root):

```
0 15 * * 6 export DISPLAY=:0 && gnome-terminal -e "/mnt/Files/Software/Software Customizations/Linux/Scripts/rsync_backup.sh"
```

but I get the following error when the file is executed

```
There was an error creating a child process for this terminal.
Failed to execute child process "/mnt/Files/Software/Software" (Permission denied)
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot error]

Can you please tell me what the problem is.
Doesn't look like a permissions issue cause I can execute the file without using sudo, and the path is only partial in the screenshot, leads me to believe it an issue with spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try escaping the space in your path:

```
0 15 * * 6 export DISPLAY=:0 && gnome-terminal -e "/mnt/Files/Software/Software\ Customizations/Linux/Scripts/rsync_backup.sh"
```

Comment: That worked, Thanks.

I had the space escaped before but I removed it when I put the double quotes. I see that you need both for it to work